# c++ boost deserialize char array into an obj

Tags: c++, serialization, boost

in boost bus schedule sample code.
[bus schedule sample](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/libs/serialization/example/demo.cpp)
I try to deserialize the data in a char array.  So I added this function.  But it has this error.  What is wrong?

```
void frombuffer_schedule(char* buffer,const bus_schedule& obj)
{     
    boost::iostreams::stream<boost::iostreams::array_source>  is(buffer, 4096);
    boost::archive::binary_iarchive ia(is,boost::archive::archive_flags::no_header);
    ia >> obj;
}
```

The error is "error: static assertion failed: typex::value"

Comment: What version of boost are you using? What file and line number is that static assertion at?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're deserializing into a `const` object. Here's the actual code around that failing assert:

```
// cannot load data into a "const" object unless it's a
// wrapper around some other non-const object.
BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT(typex::value);
```

So, fix it :)

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c3f1dc6d9ed44518)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/serialization/string.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/serialization.hpp>

struct MyData {
    std::string s;
    float values[7];

  private:
    friend class boost::serialization::access;
    template <typename Ar>
    void serialize(Ar& ar, unsigned) { ar & s & values; }
};

#include <boost/iostreams/device/array.hpp>
#include <boost/iostreams/device/back_inserter.hpp>
#include <boost/iostreams/stream.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/binary_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/binary_iarchive.hpp>
namespace bio = boost::iostreams;

std::vector<char> to_buffer(const MyData& obj) {     
    std::vector<char> buffer;

    bio::stream<bio::back_insert_device<std::vector<char> > > os(buffer);

    namespace ba = boost::archive;
    ba::binary_oarchive oa(os, ba::archive_flags::no_header);

    oa << obj;
    return buffer;
}

void from_buffer(char* buffer, MyData& obj) {     
    bio::stream<bio::array_source> is(buffer, 4096);

    namespace ba = boost::archive;
    ba::binary_iarchive ia(is, ba::archive_flags::no_header);

    ia >> obj;
}

#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

static inline std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, MyData const& object) {
    os << "s:" << std::quoted(object.s) << ", values:[";
    for (float v : object.values)
        os << " " << v;
    return os << " ]";
}

int main() {
    auto buffer = to_buffer(MyData { "hello world", { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 } });

    MyData received;
    from_buffer(buffer.data(), received);

    std::cout << "Received: " << received << "\n";
}
```

Prints

```
Received: s:"hello world", values:[ 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 ]
```